# Generic GDI+ Exception when using FromHbitmap

Tags: c#, .net, image, gdi+, gdi

I have an windows c# forms application in which copying image from one window to another.
Getting below  exception when using

```
public static System.Drawing.Bitmap FromHbitmap(IntPtr hbitmap) of system.drawing.image.
```

Exception

```
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
    at System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(IntPtr hbitmap, IntPtr hpalette)
    at System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(IntPtr hbitmap)
```

This exception occurs only when application ran in 5MegaPixel monitor. It works well in regular monitor.

I understand GDI+ limits the maximum height of an image to 65500 pixel.

Please suggest how to support FromHbitmap in 5MP monitor or is there any alternative?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? How do you "copy" images is what I'm asking. Is it drag and drop or just a traditional copy and paste? Do you have access to the image file or is it just loaded purely from memory (from outside source) ?

Comment: i haven't checked on it. its a legacy application. but since its working in regular monitors i assumed problem to be in FromHbitmap

Comment: If you work with large bitmaps, whether from screen capture or from files or streams, you could try the LEADTOOLS imaging SDK. (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). The SDK's [screen capture features](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/sc/introduction.html) have been tested with screen resolutions larger than 8 megapixels. Also, image loading, saving and processing can be done with bitmaps that are much larger than that. If you'd like to try the SDK, there's a free evaluation [here](https://leadtools.com/downloads) that comes with documentations, sample code and free technical support.